# Is there a demo on how to integrate Amazon Connect and Google DialogFlow for NLP?

Tags: dialogflow-es, amazon-connect

I would like to get an understanding as to how to use Amazon Connect’s capability to connect with the Google Dialogflow for Natural Language Processing (NLP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Lex to record the utterance, then in the validation Lambda function, you send the Lex transcript to Dialogflow. Set the Lambda function's response as appropriate based on Dialogflow's response.

Edit: While technically possible, I have a hard time seeing logical reasons for doing this - additional cost using both Lex and Lambda, and you'd have to maintain both Lex and Dialogflow. Not saying Lex is perfect but it is a good product, if you're using Amazon Connect I don't see how a cost-benefit analysis could favor the use of Dialogflow over Lex.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Amazon Connect provides NLP exclusively via [Amazon Lex](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/)